# Automate page turning with jFlip

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to have a page turn effect like the one seen on this page: [jFlip demo](http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/demo.html) except I want to automate the page turning, like make it happen every second, 20 times (or however many images I have). I want to be able to trigger this animation to run either on page load, when a button is clicked, etc.

Unfortunately I don't understand jQuery all that well and the plugin's events seem rather complicated to me, probably mostly due to my inexperience with jQuery. Any help on which direction I should go, methods I should try? I am not limiting myself to jQuery or even Javascript, this is just the example I have found that achieves my desired effect.

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't implement that plugin. That makes for terrible UX. Just use a normal [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) to rotate through your pictures.

Comment: I want the effect of a cartoon-style flip book. @royhowie

Comment: if you really want this plugin, then i can give a workaround (which includes some editing in plugin code)

Comment: @CerlinBoss that would be fantastic! It doesn't need to be this particular plugin, it's just the closest I've found to what I want, so I thought it would be a good starting place.

Comment: there are many other plugins which gives you the effect. example: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/12/best-jquery-page-flip-book-effect-with-examples/. i am not sure which one suit your requirement. If you are ok with jFlip, then i have added a function to flip the slides manually. I can share it if you want.

Comment: @CerlinBoss Turn.js was very tempting. Unfortunately, the effect on that one isn't nearly as good once it is sped up to a cartoon-like framerate (about 6 frames/sec). If you have the code added and care to explain what you changed, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the updated code [here](http://pastebin.com/AgEJPE5b). replace this with old one.

Usage :

```
var jFlip = new Flip("#g1",300,300,{background:"green",cornersTop:true,scale:"fit"}); 
// here #g1 is a jquery selector (make sure it returns only one). 
// The structure is Flip(JQselector,width,height,options)
```

then use the jFlip object to flip slides/pages

```
jFlip.flipMe() // for next slide
jFlip.flipMe(true) // for prev slide
```

for binding a function to slide change event you can use

```
$("#g1").bind("flip.jflip",function(event,index,total){
    $("#l1").html("Image "+(index+1)+" of "+total);
});
// here the selector is same as the one passed inside jFlip function.
```

Try this and let me know the feedback.